# Button with full-sized icon in Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avaloniaui

I'd like to have a Button with a full-width and full-height `PathIcon` inside (without having to manually set the `Width` and `Height` to the same pixel value of the button).

[According to the docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/layout/alignment-margins-and-padding#understanding-alignment-properties) it seems like setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `"Stretch"` *should* do the trick however using the following (simplified) XAML *(I also tried to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties of the Button to `Stretch` which aren't really documented anywhere in the Avalonia docs as far as I can tell but IntelliSense came up with them and they seemed to be related, soooo ... :)*

```xml
<Button Name="button"
        Background="Cyan"
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <PathIcon Background="Red"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Name="normalIcon"
            Data="{StaticResource copy}"/>
</Button>
```

leads to this result:

[image]

As can be seen the red icon doesn't cover the complete cyan button. I triple-checked for any `Margin`s or `Padding`s that could interfere but there are none.

Now the obvious (and quite ugly) solution here would be to do something like this:

```xml
<Button Name="button"
        Background="Cyan"
        Width="50"
        Height="50">
  <PathIcon Background="Red"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Name="normalIcon"
            Data="{StaticResource copy}"/>
</Button>
```

which probably would work but only for this simplified example. In reality my button contains a panel which then contains several icons that would be conditionally toggled (`IsVisible="True/False"`) so setting `Width` and `Height` to the same value for all of them just isn't practical (especially in case these values would have to be changed in the future).

I've already taken a look at questions like [How to set width to 100% in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787436/how-to-set-width-to-100-in-wpf), [How to get button content to fill width in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647009/how-to-get-button-content-to-fill-width-in-wpf) and [WPF: Setting the Width (and Height) as a Percentage Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717299/wpf-setting-the-width-and-height-as-a-percentage-value)
 but neither of them seem to do the trick (either because I'm not using them correctly or because there are just too many differences between [avaloniaui](/questions/tagged/avaloniaui) and [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)?)

What I'd basically like to achieve is something similar to this CSS snippet

```css
Button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

Button > Panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Button > Panel > PathIcon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

#### What I've also tried:

- [Using a `DockPanel` and setting `LastChildFill="True"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031029/9745732) (Didn't work - while the `DockPanel` **did** fill the button (*for the most part anyways*) the `PathIcon` (the last child of the dock panel) seemed like it couldn't care less about that it *should* fill the `DockPanel` :|
- [Doing some trickery with `ControlTemplate`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647485/9745732) (Didn't work - then again I'm not going to pretend that I knew what I was doing when I tried it, nor if this is even the correct approach in [avaloniaui](/questions/tagged/avaloniaui) :P

#### So how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalAlignment worked in Button

```
 <Button Content="Add Element"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></Button>
```

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPMhU.png)